# remote server performance when scraping

Tags: python, performance, web-scraping, scrapy

I have used the following problem in other questions, but this time my question regards server performance. And so, I decided to ask a new question.

I try to run the spider below. It only has to go through 2478 pages, but still I have performance problems. Initially, it took about 2.5 hours to scrape the data with the following settings:

```
LOG_ENABLED = True
CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN = 2
RETRY_TIMES = 20
DOWNLOAD_DELAY = 5
```

Which to me seems very slow. To speed up the spider I then set `HTTPCACHE_ENABLED = True` but after the first 100 pages the spider only returned "500 Internal Server Error", and I couldn't even view the webpages in the browser.

Any thought on why I receive this error? And what do I do to avoid this problem?

My code is the following:

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.item import Item, Field
import re

class Sale(Item):
    Adresse = Field()
    Pris = Field()
    Salgsdato = Field()
    SalgsType = Field()
    KvmPris = Field()
    Rum = Field()
    Postnummer = Field()
    Boligtype = Field()
    Kvm = Field()
    Bygget = Field()

class HouseSpider(BaseSpider):
    name = 'House'
    allowed_domains = ["http://boliga.dk/"]
    start_urls = ['http://www.boliga.dk/salg/resultater?so=1&type=Villa&type=Ejerlejlighed&type=R%%C3%%A6kkehus&type=Fritidshus&type=Landejendom&type=Andet&kom=&amt=&fraPostnr=&tilPostnr=&iPostnr=&gade=&min=&max=&byggetMin=&byggetMax=&minRooms=&maxRooms=&minSize=&maxSize=&minsaledate=1993&maxsaledate=1994&kode=&p=%d' %n for n in xrange(1, 2479, 1)]

    def parse(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        sites = hxs.select("id('searchresult')/tr")
        items = []      
        for site in sites:
            item = Sale()
            item['Adresse'] = site.select("td[1]/a[1]/text()").extract()
            item['Pris'] = site.select("td[2]/text()").extract()
            item['Salgsdato'] = site.select("td[3]/text()").extract()
            Temp = site.select("td[4]/text()").extract()
            Temp = Temp[0]
            m = re.search('\r\n\t\t\t\t\t(.+?)\r\n\t\t\t\t', Temp)
            if m:
                found = m.group(1)
                item['SalgsType'] = found
            else:
                item['SalgsType'] = Temp
            item['KvmPris'] = site.select("td[5]/text()").extract()
            item['Rum'] = site.select("td[6]/text()").extract()
            item['Postnummer'] = site.select("td[7]/text()").extract()
            item['Boligtype'] = site.select("td[8]/text()").extract()
            item['Kvm'] = site.select("td[9]/text()").extract()
            item['Bygget'] = site.select("td[10]/text()").extract()
            items.append(item)
        return items
```

Thanks!

Comment: What is the "my server" you refer to? Are you running this code inside a WSGI app or something? If so, the obvious thing to try is running the same code in a local interpreter, to take anything related to your server out of the equation. If the problem's still there, you've got your answer, right?

Comment: Anyway, many web servers deliberately throttle overly-aggressive clients, because (a) they've got a proper web service they want you to use instead, (b) they don't want you to read all their info without seeing all their ads, (c) they don't want anyone to have all their info because that's where their actual value is, and/or (d) they don't want to pay for all that bandwidth. (Many smaller sites use hosting providers that throttle automatically, but in that case it's basically (d).)

Comment: @abarnert: I am just running the spider from my laptop and an internet connection, so talking about "my server" is probably just me not fully understanding whats is going on. Sorry about that.

Comment: @abarnert: I think (d) is a plausible explanation, since the data isn't proprietary. But how do I adjust my spider so that it is not overly-aggressive?

Comment: I removed the "my server" part, and hopefully made the question clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Initially, it took about 2.5 hours to scrape the data with the following settings:
>
> LOG_ENABLED = True
> CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN = 2
> RETRY_TIMES = 20
> DOWNLOAD_DELAY = 5

You're asking it to wait 5 seconds before downloading consecutive pages from the same site. That's what [`DOWNLOAD_DELAY`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#std:setting-DOWNLOAD_DELAY) means. It will actually wait a random amount of time between 2.5 and 7.5 seconds, and sometimes it will have two simultaneous requests in flight, and so on… but the expected value for downloading 2478 pages this way is 5 * 2477 = 12385 seconds = 3:26:25.

If setting `HTTPCACHE_ENABLED` makes a difference, apparently you've already run it for 3.5 hours before and have most of it still live in the same cache dir. (You can't be breaking things and making it download the same pages repeatedly, because you're feeding `BaseSpider` a static list of pages, and not returning any `Request` objects from `parse`.)

---

But the easy way to debug this is to take all of your code out of the way. Generate a list of addresses and try to just download them with `curl` or `wget` or something.

When I tried this, even with 10 second delays between requests, nearly all of them took ~20 seconds to return a 500 error, and a few of them never responded at all. That certainly seems like a server problem to me. So, there's nothing you can do about it, except maybe contact the server administrator.

Comment: Fair enough, but how can I use this to solve the "500 Internal Server Error" problem I get?

Comment: Okay, thanks. Right now, I think the server is having problems, but in general is the `download_delay` the best/only way to avoid server problems?

Comment: @Mace The server may be having issues, or it may end up temporarily blocking you for making too many requests in a period of time (which can effectively work as a DoS attack if there are too many requests per second). Setting a download delay is good if you want to prevent your IP address from being blocked, and to prevent potential DoS situations. The bigger the delay, the slower your script will be though, obviously.

Comment: @Anorov: Thanks, I have no interest in crashing their server (of course!) or immitating a DoS attack, so I will definitely crawl less aggresively and accept the slower script. To go past a possible block will it typically be enough to change internet connection or should I also change computer?

Comment: @Anorov: Since I had the same problems as him from my very first request, and 100% of a couple dozen requests, no closer together than 10 seconds apart, I'm pretty sure the server was actually down, not just blocking him. (I suppose it's possible that he's right down the street from me with the same ISP and they overzealously blocked the whole range… but very unlikely.)

Comment: @Mace: Given that the problem was the server being down, there is, as I said, "nothing you can do about it, except maybe contact the server administrator". It's possible that you accidentally contributed to breaking the server, but with a 5-second delay, it's not likely. And there's no evidence they were blocking you, so there's no point trying to work around that. Your existing delay should be fine.